# how to select dropdown having Encoding::UndefinedConversionError in watir?

Tags: ruby, utf-8, watir, utf8-decode

I want to select dropdown having **text="Côte d'Ivoire"**.

```
ie.select_list(:id, "name01").select("#{text}")
```

**I tried these codes,**

1.encoding: UTF-8 #not working

2.text.force_encoding("ASCII-8BIT").encode('UTF-8', undef: :replace, replace:'')
     #text=Cte d'Ivoire

**what should I do for it?**
**I also want to save this text to my DB.Please help.**

Comment: Could you please add an error message (possibly full stack trace) and specify what versions of Ruby and Watir are you using?

Comment: @jnv Encoding::UndefinedConversionError,It is due to text="Côte d'Ivoire" as it contains some ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 conversion.
ruby version is ruby193

Answer (score 0):

If you know the string is UTF-8 encoded, why not just force encoding to UTF-8?

```
#encoding: ASCII-8BIT
str = "C\xC3\xB4te d'Ivoire" # => "C\xC3\xB4te d'Ivoire"
str.encoding # => #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>

str.force_encoding('UTF-8')
str # => "Côte d'Ivoire"
str.encoding # => #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

If you are using `Côte d'Ivoire` as a literal anywhere in your Ruby source files, be sure to add

```
#encoding: UTF-8
```

as the first line of the file to tell Ruby that the file is UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: I tried this thing already and I also mentioned of it in my question.i.e. it did not work for me as I was trying to select dropdown with this text.

Comment: Your question shows you used different arguments to the function.

Comment: problem is that when I use these options .These replace "Côte d'Ivoire" the characters of my text which create problems.so when I select my dropdown on the basis of text value , No value found error comes.

Answer (score 0):

I would have expected your solutions to work, unless the software you are using to save/execute the files is overriding the setting. I recall having that issue with NetBeans.

An alternative, if you cannot fix the actual encoding, is to use a regex to match just the standard characters.

```
text = /C.te d'Ivoire/
browser.select_list.select(text)
```

The regex has replaced all accented characters with a `.`.

Not a great solution, but perhaps a solution if nothing else works.

Comment: the problem is that there are 30(may be more) select options of a dropdown in a webpage.I put all these in a array and then use foreach loop on this array to select the drop down of that page to test some thing.there are 12 select options which create this problem , i just mention only one i.e.  text="Côte d'Ivoire"

Comment: If you are looping through all of the options, why do you need to select them by text?

Comment: then how shall I select all my drop down options? I want to select them  individually one by one to check some thing.

Comment: You can iterate through all the options and select each one - `browser.select_list(:id, "name01").options.each{ |o| o.select; #do something }`